# How to avoid two floats on the same page?

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a document with a few figures and tables. The figures are all specified as `[t]` and the tables as `[b]`. Right now, the compiler sometimes places two floats on the same page, leaving little space for the actual text on that page.

I would like each float to show up on a separate page, along with the text. This might come at the expense of increasing the number of pages for the document, but that is okay. How can I prevent two floats being placed on the same page?

Ideally, I would like to only prevent two top floats or two bottom floats on the same page, while still allowing one top and one bottom float.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow only one float per page, use:

```
\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}
```

To instead allow one top and one bottom float, use:

```
\setcounter{topnumber}{1}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{2}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea how to only avoid two top floats or two bottom floats on the same page, while allowing one top float and one bottom float?

Comment: @danijar set topnumber and bottomnumber to 1 and totalnumber to 2 (it's a bit unfair to change the question after an answer posted, but I'm sure the poster here can edit the answer:-)

Comment: Thanks again. I actually did not change the question, I already mentioned this in the last paragraph of my question. I proposed an edit to combine the two answers and add a line of context for each solution.

Comment: @danijar oh sorry, I misread the timings:-)